# Getting the sessionKey using Facebook-Java API

Tags: java, facebook, session, key

I am developing a Facebook application. In this application, I use Java API provided by Google and the application is based on web.

I have the `facebook_api_key` and `facebook_secrete`, but how to get the `sessionKey`?

This code is not web-based:

```
FacebookJsonRestClient client = new FacebookJsonRestClient(Test.API_KEY, Test.SECRET);
String token = client.auth_createToken();
String url = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=";
url += Test.API_KEY;
url += "&v=1.0";
url += "&auth_token=";
url += token;
String strCommand = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE ";
strCommand += url;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strCommand);
// wait until the login process is completed
// fetch session key
String session = client.auth_getSession(token, true);
......
```

I want to change it to a web-based one.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try this way:

```
String sessionKey = request.getParameter(FacebookParam.SESSION_KEY.toString());

FacebookXmlRestClient client = new FacebookXmlRestClient(FB_API_KEY, FB_SECRET_KEY, sessionKey);
```

I also suggest the [FaceBook Developer Forum Dicussion](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=137895) and [an article](http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/facebook-java-api-example-to-publish-on-wall/) describe about generating session keys. I thought it could be helpful to you..